# Line break using multirow and fitting to the table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multirow, arrays

I have a table with some `multirow` cells. Sometimes the cell content is wider than the cell, the it has to make a breakline. Reading a little, I founded that specifying the `multirow` width, the text will automatically break, however, after the linebreak, the text stay outside of the cell. How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}}
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
 \textbf{Row 1}  & \multirow{2}{*}{A longer text for line break} & Text row 1\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
 \textbf{Row 2}  & & Text row 2\\
\midrule
 \textbf{Row 3}  & Text row 3 & A longer text for line break\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}}
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
 \textbf{Row 1}  & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering A longer text for line break} & Text row 1\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
 \textbf{Row 2}  & & Text row 2\\
\midrule
 \textbf{Row 3}  & Text row 3 & A longer text for line break\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the multirow cell has 3 lines whereas the corresponding table rows are only two.

I think you could solve the problem increasing the height of those two rows by some struts and some spaces added at the end of them.

By the way, `multicol` package is used to have two columns of text, it is not necessary to use `\multicolumn` (from its position in your MWE I think you thought that).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}}
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
 \myrule\textbf{Row 1}  & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering A longer text for line break} & \myrule Text row 1\\[4pt]
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
 \myrule\textbf{Row 2}  & & \myrule Text row 2\\[4pt]
\midrule
 \textbf{Row 3}  & Text row 3 & A longer text for line break\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]